# Zend Framework URL Rewriting Using Htaccess

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, url-rewriting

#### Guys,

I want to write a .htaccess rewrite rule in zend framwork.

MY URL is http://www.somedomain.com:8090/hotel-profile

I want to redirect this URL to http://www.somedomain.com:8090/disabled

So to achieve this goal I have added following to my existing .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule  ^hotel-profile$ /disabled
```

But it is not working for me.

my .htaccess files looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule  ^hotel-profile$ /disabled 

# Activate Zend Framework.
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a plugin which use a predispatch method? This could be usefull if you want to add more redirects like this.